# Table name in procedure is not a known variable

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a procedure in PostgreSQL by following these [instruction](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html).
My table is following code

```
CREATE TABLE public.sinh_vien (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    ma_sinh_vien numeric NULL,
    ten_sinh_vien varchar(50) NULL,
    ngay_sinh date NULL
);
```

Here is my  procedure

```
create or replace
function sinh_vien_merge(datainput json) returns character varying language plpgsql as $function$
begin
merge
into
    public.sinh_vien w
        using (
values(
select
    x.id ,
    x.ma_sinh_vien ,
    x.ten_sinh_vien ,
    to_date(x.ngay_sinh , 'dd/MM/yyyy') ngay_sinh
from
    (
    select
        *
    from
        json_populate_recordset(null::record, dataInput :: json) as ( id numeric,
        ma_sinh_vien numeric,
        ten_sinh_vien varchar,
        ngay_sinh varchar )) x)) v on
    v.id = w.id
    when not matched
insert
    (ma_sinh_vien,
    ten_sinh_vien,
    ngay_sinh)
values(v.ma_sinh_vien,
v.ten_sinh_vien,
v.ngay_sinh)
when matched
update
set
    ma_sinh_vien = v.ma_sinh_vien;

ten_sinh_vien = v.ten_sinh_vien,
ngay_sinh = v.ngay_sinh; 
return '1';
end;
```

I got an message

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: "public.sinh_vien" is not a known variable

How do I solve this?

Comment: What version of Postgresql are you using? The official release documentation does not have a MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice, that there is no `MERGE` in PostgreSQL. Your linked documentation is the "PostgreSQL 8.4devel Documentation", but the `MERGE` command never made it to a productive version.

Thus you cannot use `MERGE` in your function. You will need to "build" its functionalities with your own `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands.

Comment: Can i use `INSERT` command with `on conflic` event ? In my case is conflic (id)

Comment: I guess you can, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in [Postgres 15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html).